# Building Neyman-Pearson test in 2D-space having only data for $H_0$ and $H_1$

Tags: likelihood-ratio, signal-detection, neyman-pearson-lemma

Suppose we have some statistical data which is points in 2D-space. More precise sample space is upper right quarter of $\mathbb{R^2}$:
$$\Omega = \{X | X=(x_1, x_2),\, x_1, x_2\in \mathbb{R_+}\}$$

The problem can be formulated as the following:

> Given a significance level $\alpha$ and two sample sets which is known that one of them is a signal and other is a background (see figures):
>   \begin{align}
> S = \{(x_1, x_2)\,|\,H_0\}\\
> B = \{(y_1, y_2)\,|\,H_1\}
> \end{align}
>   determine critical region $S_c\subset\Omega$ that gives largest power $1-\beta$ with respect to $H_1$. In other words, it is needed to choose a region in order to reject as much background as possible accepting signal with the efficiency *a*.

The problem is more about some computational algorithm rather than some theoretical approach. Though everything is connected.

---

EDIT: Maybe one should require that $S_c$ is simply connected in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

[image: Signal events]
[image: Background events]

Comment: Since you can make any (not topologically wild) non-simply connected region into a simply connected one by removing a set of measure zero (with respect to both hypotheses), simple-connectivity is not a useful criterion.  The problem of finding a critical region is relatively straightforward; the key is to estimate $H_0$ and $H_1$ and then to assess how data variability affects that critical region.  Your knowledge of and assumptions about the hypotheses should help you identify suitable estimation procedures.  Can you provide more details?